# Static Objects in a Class (Singleton)

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, static, singleton

I'm looking at two implementations of the Singleton design pattern.

I wanted to know how the second one works, in particular:

1. Why has the author chosen to return DB as a reference.
2. Why does the static class object DB in getDatabaseConnection() not need to be defined outside of the SingleDatabase class as such:

```
SingletonDatabase& SingletonDatabase::DB;
```

3. Does a static class object, like a static variable, only get created once (and is shared amongst all objects of the same class)?

**Implementation**

```
class SingletonDatabase {
    private:
        SingletonDatabase() {
            std::cout << "Initializing database" << std::endl;
            instanceCount++; // Used in testing later on.
        }

    public:
        SingletonDatabase(const SingletonDatabase&) = delete;
        SingletonDatabase& operator=(const SingletonDatabase&) = delete;
        static SingletonDatabase& getDatabaseConnection() {
            static SingletonDatabase DB;
            return DB;
        }
        static int instanceCount;
};

int SingletonDatabase::instanceCount = 0;
```

I'm used to seeing the implementation with a static pointer, which the author mentioned is not thread safe. He prefers this method.

Thanks!

Comment: What you call "static object" and "static variable" are in fact the same. The symbol `DB` is a variable. The variable contains the object.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Why has the author chosen to return DB as a reference.

Instead of a reference, a pointer could have been used as well. The reference expresses better that the pointee is granted to exist. (Return by value instead would have corrupted the concept.)

> 2. Why does the static class object DB in getDatabaseConnection() not need to be defined outside of the SingleDatabase class as such:
>
> `SingletonDatabase& SingletonDatabase::DB;`

It's not a member variable but a `static` variable with a local scope but the life-time of a static → granted to exist from first access until end of process.

[SO: What is the lifetime of a static variable in a C++ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246568/7478597) (a little bit aged but still correct)

This would've been worked the same way in a plain function. That the surrounding function is a (`static` member function) is not that relevant concerning this.

> 3. Does a static class object, like a static variable, only get created once (and is shared amongst all objects of the same class)?

Yes.

To be correct, it's shared between any caller of this function.

---

Btw. this is known as **Meyers Singleton**:

[FleCSI: Meyer’s Singleton](http://laristra.github.io/flecsi/src/developer-guide/patterns/meyers_singleton.html) → [SO: C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/7478597)

[SO: Is Meyers' implementation of the Singleton pattern thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661529/7478597)

Comment: Shouldn't we do the `=delete` for the move constructors as well?

Comment: @Gupta I assumed that `delete`ing the copy constructor deletes the implicit move constructor as well. Uncertain, whether [Implicitly-declared move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor) really proves me right, I googled and found [SO: If I delete the copy constructor, do I get no implicit move constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26803634/7478597). It seems, my assumption is valid.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Scheff's points:

> I'm used to seeing the implementation with a static pointer, which the
>   author mentioned is not thread safe. He prefers this method.

As [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379162/singleton-class-implementation-using-shared-ptr) shows, implementing the singleton pattern with pointers is not thread-safe.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked three questions, the third of which has been answered.